# FileSystemWatcher event called - debugger jumps around

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I've gone through a lot of posts here about the FileSystemWatcher and its issues.
I thought that I set it up properly but I'm finding the event handler is doing some weird things.

I've set up a FileSystemWatcher in a class library project where it looks for a specific file that is dropped.  When that file is dropped - the code will then extract the values of the text file and print it out.

When this piece of code is executed and the file is dropped - it will properly go to the file system event handler. And the code will extract the text file values and print. 
Once every so often it will print off multiple copies of the dropped file. 
So I put a debugger on it in Visual Studio. 
What i've noticed is once it goes into the event handler the debugger jumps all over the place.  It's the jumping around that makes it print more than once sometimes.

Have I missed something that would allow the debugger and code to run from beginning to end without multiple calls to extract and print?

thanks.

Here is the code to set up the watcher (I just took chunks - don't mind if it's not in good format):

```
    private void WatchMainDropFile()
    {
        fileSystemWatcherMain = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcherMain.Path = Constants.FolderPath;
        fileSystemWatcherMain.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
        fileSystemWatcherMain.Filter = DropFileName;
        fileSystemWatcherMain.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnMainDropFileCreated);
        fileSystemWatcherMain.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```

Here is the event code:

```
    private void OnMainDropFileCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Disable the watcher
        fileSystemWatcherMain.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        fileSystemWatcherMain.Created -= new FileSystemEventHandler(OnMainDropFileCreated);

        try
        {
            if ((File.Exists(e.FullPath)))
            {
                //Print out contents of the file
                ExtractFileForPrinting();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Catch the error here later.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is in general to be expected when the FSW events fire for multiple files.  Something you can see from the debugger's Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window, you probably see multiple threads executing your code.  Test it with only *one* file change at a time to keep it sane.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your reply. It's weird. If I create a console application just to look if a file (e.g. text file) - I can see the event handler being called twice with the debugger on but it does two passes. With the code in the class library (that we're using for integration purposes) the debugger just bounces around.  i can trap for the multiple passes by doing a boolean check in the console app but it doesn't seem to work with the class library where it bounces. Any idea of why it seems "straight forward" in the console app but not in the class library?  thanks.